# No sound after connecting to Bluetooth Device (wf-1000xm3)

Tags: arch-linux, pulseaudio, bluetooth, pipewire

Bluetoothctl shows my WF-1000xm3 ear phones connected. But, the earphones do not give the accoustic feedback 'bluetooth connected' and also sound does not work.

Below is the output of bluetoothctl.

```
$ bluetoothctl connect 14:3F:A6:81:00:38

Attempting to connect to 14:3F:A6:81:00:38
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:81:00:38 RSSI: -56
[CHG] Device 14:3F:A6:81:00:38 Connected: yes
Connection successful
```

I use EndeavourOS and installed PipeWire. The troubleshooting section of the Arch's PipeWire Wiki (https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PipeWire), covers the problem "No sound after connecting to Bluetooth device". It refers to a udev script (https://gist.github.com/tinywrkb/04e7fd644afa9b92d33a3a99ab07ee9e), from which I copied this terminal comand

```
(pactl list sinks|grep Name|grep 'bluez.*.a2dp.sink'|sed 's/Name: //'|sed 's/\s//')
```

Which did not show any available devices.

Any idea, what the issue might be?

###### EDIT

I can connect to my JBL Loudspeakers and have no issues with sound. So, the issue is related to my WF-1000xm3 earphones.

Comment: Apart from the `pactl` one-liner deserving serious editing, if `$ pactl list sinks` does not list your earphones it is because they are ***not*** registered as a sink. Normally, you need to create a null-sink (e.g. `$ pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Redirected_Audio sink_properties=device.description=Redirected_Audio`). Then redirect your null-sink to your earphones (`$ pactl load-module module-loopback source=Redirected_Audio.monitor sink=name_of_headphones`). The `udev` part of your post may constitute another problem but that is for another (separate) post.

Comment: @Cbhihe so, this two lines should create the null-sink and redirect the audio to the ear phones? which exact name does pactl expect for "name_of_headphones". Is it the one, which is shown in bluetoothctl (i.e. LE_WF1000XM3)?